# How to define a struct for a predicate to be used in a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, stl, predicate

I would like to use `std::stable_partition` for removing entries from a `std::vector`. The vector is a member of a template class in some library **A**. I am trying to setup a struct called `Checker` with an `operator()` to act as predicate for `std::stable_partition`.

My questions seems related to [How do I define a sort predicate for a templated container class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24174103/8631630) but in my case the argument to the predicate depends on the templates (across two DLLs)

Some DLL **A**:

**VectorKey2GenericPtr.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <class KEY_TYPE, class GENERIC_TYPE>
class VectorKey2GenericPtr
{
protected:
    std::vector< std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE*> > m_Vector;
    std::set<KEY_TYPE> m_keysToBeRemoved;
public:
    void Remove(const std::set<KEY_TYPE>& keysOfEntriesToBeRemoved);
protected:
    struct Checker
    {
      std::set<KEY_TYPE> m_keysToBeRemoved;
      explicit Checker(std::set<KEY_TYPE>& keysToBeRemoved):m_keysToBeRemoved(keysToBeRemoved) {}
      //bool operator() (const std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE>& pairToBeTested) <-- before fix suggested by @MassimilianoJanes
      bool operator() (const std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE*>& pairToBeTested)
      {
        const KEY_TYPE& keyToBeTested = pairToBeTested.first;
        typename std::set<KEY_TYPE>::iterator it = m_keysToBeRemoved.find(keyToBeTested);
        bool found = false;
        if (it != m_keysToBeRemoved.end())
        {
          found = true;
          m_keysToBeRemoved.erase(it);
        }
        return found;
      }
    };
};
```

**VectorKey2GenericPtr.cpp**

```
#include "VectorKey2GenericPtr.h"
#include <functional>

template <class KEY_TYPE, class GENERIC_TYPE>
void VectorKey2GenericPtr<KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE>::
Remove(const std::set<KEY_TYPE>& keysOfEntriesToBeRemoved)
{
  m_keysToBeRemoved = keysOfEntriesToBeRemoved;
  typename std::vector< std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE*> >::iterator bound;

  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // !!!  I would like to use Checker like this: !!!
  bound = std::stable_partition( m_Vector.begin(), m_Vector.end(), Checker(m_keysToBeRemoved) );
  //
  // TODO: Remove one partition from the map
  //
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

}

class SomeInterfaceFromDLLB;
template class VectorKey2GenericPtr<int, SomeInterfaceFromDLLB>;

template class VectorKey2GenericPtr<int, SomeInterfaceFromDLLB>::Checker;
```

some DLL **B**:

**SomeInterfaceFromDLLB.h**

```
class SomeInterfaceFromDLLB{};
```

---

**EDIT1**

After comment by @Massimiliano Janes my original compilation error:

> C2079 `std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE>::second` uses undefined class `SomeInterfaceFromDLLB'

Has been fixed by changing:

> Checker: 'bool operator() (const std::pair& pairToBeTested)`

to

> Checker: bool operator() (const std::pair& pairToBeTested)

Now I am still getting the following error:

> C2166 l-value specifies const object

This is related to the line:

```
bound = std::stable_partition( m_Vector.begin(), m_Vector.end(), Checker(m_keysToBeRemoved) );
```

**utility.h:**

```
_Myt& operator=(_Myt&& _Right)
 _NOEXCEPT_OP((is_nothrow_move_assignable<_Ty1>::value && is_nothrow_move_assignable<_Ty2>::value))
  { // assign from moved pair
    first = _STD forward<_Ty1>(_Right.first);
    second = _STD forward<_Ty2>(_Right.second);
    return (*this);
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the checker operator()  should take a std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE*> not a std::pair<const KEY_TYPE, GENERIC_TYPE>, is it a typo ?

Comment: by the way, if you only want to remove elements from the vector, std::remove_if will be more efficient than std::stable_partition

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes : Thanks for your comments:
1) Yes, you are right. I corrected it.
2) But I would like to redefined the keys so there are no 'holes' in the numbering.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes: Thanks for your comments: 1) Fixed the compilation error !

Comment: `stable_partition` needs to move elements around, in part by assigning new values to existing elements. But elements of your vector are not assignable, by reason of having a `const` member. If you insist on keeping that, your only option is `std::copy_if` or `std::partition_copy` or similar - copying elements into a different vector in the right order.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for this explanation. That makes perfectly sense.